# unable to figure out the test case for wrong output

Tags: c

This is the problem statement

https://www.codechef.com/status/TLG
I have written this code, but it is failing some test case.... and I cant figure out which one,It is working fine on the test cases I tried but when I submitted it on codechef it didnt pass a test case it seems,can someone please help.... Thank you !

The game of billiards involves two players knocking 3 balls around on a green baize table. Well, there is more to it, but for our purposes this is sufficient.

The game consists of several rounds and in each round both players obtain a score, based on how well they played. Once all the rounds have been played, the total score of each player is determined by adding up the scores in all the rounds and the player with the higher total score is declared the winner.

The Siruseri Sports Club organises an annual billiards game where the top two players of Siruseri play against each other. The Manager of Siruseri Sports Club decided to add his own twist to the game by changing the rules for determining the winner. In his version, at the end of each round, the cumulative score for each player is calculated, and the leader and her current lead are found. Once all the rounds are over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in the game is declared the winner.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
{
    int n,p1[n],p2[n],lead1[n],lead2[n];
    //printf("Enter no of entries:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    //printf("Enter scores....\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        //printf("Enter player 1 score:");
        scanf("%d",&p1[i]);
        printf("Enter player 2 score:");
        scanf("%d",&p2[i]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        lead1[i]=p1[i]-p2[i];
        lead2[i]=p2[i]-p1[i];
    }
    int temp1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(lead1[i]>lead1[j])
            {
                temp1=lead1[i];
                lead1[i]=lead1[j];
                lead1[j]=temp1;
            }
            
        }
    }
     int temp2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(lead2[i]>lead2[j])
            {
                temp2=lead2[i];
                lead2[i]=lead2[j];
                lead2[j]=temp2;
            }
            
        }
    }
    if(lead1[n-1]>lead2[n-1])
    {
        printf("1 %d",lead1[n-1]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("2 %d",lead2[n-1]);   
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int n,p1[n],p2[n],lead1[n],lead2[n];` - you can't define arrays of unknown size (that is with `n` uninitialized). So *any* testcase is invalid, because the program is invalid.

Comment: what if I initialize the array after taking input for n, will it work then ?@EugeneSh.

Comment: The simplest thing would be to define the array to have the maximum size possible. The problem statement contains this constraint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't need to store the scores for each round in an array at all.

You only need a two element array, indexed by player number, to hold the total/accumulated scores

Just remember the "best" round (largest lead) and the player that had it as you read in the data.

Here's what I came up with [it passes the submission for all data]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char *cp;
    int nround;
    int round;
    int curdif;
    int curlead;
    int bestlead = -1;
    int bestdif = -1;
    int pidx;
    int pcur[2];
    int ptot[2] = { 0 };
    char buf[100];

    // get number of rounds
    fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);
    nround = strtol(buf,&cp,10);

    for (round = 1;  round <= nround;  ++round) {
        fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin);

        // read in current round score and get cumulative score for all players
        cp = buf;
        for (pidx = 0;  pidx <= 1;  ++pidx) {
            pcur[pidx] = strtol(cp,&cp,10);
            ptot[pidx] += pcur[pidx];
            ++cp;
        }

        // get cumulative score difference and the current lead value
        curdif = ptot[0] - ptot[1];
        if (curdif < 0)
            curlead = -curdif;
        else
            curlead = curdif;

        // remember the largest lead and the largest difference [the sign of
        // that is related to the player number]
        if (curlead > bestlead) {
            bestlead = curlead;
            bestdif = curdif;
        }
    }

    printf("%d %d\n",(bestdif < 0) ? 2 : 1,bestlead);

    return 0;
}
```